# Function for putting all database table to an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a function to print database table to an array like this

```
$db_array=  
 Array(
    ID=>1,
    PARENTID =>1,
    TITLE => LIPSUM,
    TEXT =>LIPSUM
    )
```

My function is:

```
function dbToArray($table)
                        {
                          $allArrays =array();
                          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
                          $dbRow = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                            for ($i=0; $i<count($dbRow)  ; $i++)
                                {
                                   $allArrays[$i] =  $dbRow; 
                                }
                            $txt .='<pre>';
                            $txt .= print_r($allArrays);
                            $txt .= '</pre>';
                            return $txt;
                        }
```

Anything wrong in my function. Any help is appreciated about my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `if` (you get some error) `then` paste the error;

Comment: Not any error but output is repeated 21 times:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [ID] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [PARENTID] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [CATID] => 1
            [3] => Newss
            [CATNAME] => Newss
            [4] => 1
            )
)

Comment: This is probably because your table contains 21 columns. And you are looping on the same row over and over. mysql_fetch_array() returns only one row. So if you want to move to other rows. It should be called over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure your function will get all the rows returned by the database. [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns only one row. So the for loop is pretty pointless.

Instead you should something like this instead of the for loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) {
  $allArrays[] = $row;
}
```

by the way if you still want to use the for loop you could try something like this. `But what would be the point?` the while loop works perfectly for this.

```
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($query);
for($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
  $allArrays[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
```

Comment: output is:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [ID] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [PARENTID] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [CATID] => 1
            [3] => Newss
            [CATNAME] => Newss
            [4] => 1
            [BASEID] => 1
            [5] => 2010-03-19 01:10:51
            [TARIH] => 2010-03-19 01:10:51
            [6] => News Head
            [BASLIK] => News Head
            [7] => Lorem ipsum dolor  
            [MANSET] => Lorem ipsum 
                   )

)

        )

)
BTW I want a function to print arrays...

Comment: just change your for loop with one of above. And add a second parameter 'true' to print_r like @jwandborg said.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to print a table (not a database)

```
function printTable($table){
   $allRows = array();
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $allArrays[] =  $row; 
   }
   $txt ='<pre>';
   $txt .= print_r($allRows, true);
   $txt .= '</pre>';

   echo $txt;

   return $txt;
}
```

*(Edit: fixed missing second parameter in print_r)*

Comment: `print_r( $allRows );` should be `print_r( $allRows, true );`. See http://php.net/print_r

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it'll work, but kind of defeats the purpose of a relational database.. Why not just serialize your data and write it to a file?

Comment: Hi Brendan;
I do this (serialize data and write it to a file?). But im looking for a global function to do this.

Comment: It looks like it will only show the first row over and over again.